# Local RDLC report file with custom IEnumerable<>

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services, reporting, rdlc

I am trying to create a local mode (rdlc) report in my web application.

The source for my report is an IEnumerable of type Customer, each of which has a nested IEnumerable of CustomerOrders as a property.

I'm confused how to create a RDLC report that can show all of the customers, and for each customer show all of the orders.

[This post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/magreer/archive/2008/10/16/setting-the-datasource-for-a-report-at-runtime.aspx)  talks about how to create a dataset with a format that matches your IEnumerable format, and then substitute it at run time with the actual data you want to use, but I don't know how to define a dataset that matches this IEnumerable, and besides it seems somewhat clunky that I'd need to define a dataset for a report when I have a perfectly good type..

Is this possible in RDLC files?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out that I could do this by following these steps:

1) In a service class, I expose a dummy method that returns an IEnumerable

2) When I create a new local RDLC, using the wizard, I can select this method as the source of the report. I don't have to use that method, but it allows the report to read my type and gives me the properties from my enumerable to use in my report.

3) When it comes to running the report, I can then in my code behind, specify the actual data I want to use for the report:

```
this.ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("ReportDataSource", dataForReport));
```

Hope this helps someone!

Answer (score -1):

Here is a really good example of doing something similar to what you are trying to do:

http://www.gotreportviewer.com/masterdetail/index.html

This also includes code sample downloads.  Basically you will want to embed a table into a list.